# Wait for a HTTP post to Complete and then make HTTP GET AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Am working on a maintenance project which is developed on Spring, Java and Angular 1 and am trying to fix a bug with the system.

Scenario
1. When a Angular template is loaded it Calls a function example getData, it fetches set of questions and answers 
2. Update the questions and answers and click save it calls for example updateData api, it will insert/update the data in DB

Issue: 
When question and answer is updated in scenario 2, there is a Sequence which increment and updates @ID  column of the table. 
The value of id is available in angular scope only when getData API is called.

Challenge is getData API is called when updateData is being executed. 
I want getData to be called only when updateData is executed successfully.

Calls the SaveData API,

```
    var promise = 
    $q.all([UpdateService.saveData(questionAnswers, 
    $scope.contentStrategy.id)])

    promise.then(function(result)
    {
    //I want below function to get called only when above post call is complete this will make APis calls to get details updated by SaveData
    $scope.getData();
    });
```

SaveData function,

```
    saveData: function 
    (answers, answerId) {
    SaveQuestionAnswerResource.save({QuestionId: 
    answerArray[0].QuestionId}, dataToBeSave);
    }
```

SaveData api call,

```
     var SaveQuestionAnswerResource = $resource('/data- 
     api/strategy/someStrategy/someSubStrategy/:QuestionId/answers/', {questionId: '@questionId'}, {
    save: {
    method:'POST',
    isArray: true
    }
    });
```

Comment: Which "below function" are you talking about? Which "above post call"? Please simplify your code by removing all the irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Save Data API is the post am talking about.

Comment: Again, extremely unclear. You keep talking about getData() and updateData(), but there isn't any function in the code named that way. And your saveData() function isn't called anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$q.all()` expects an array of promises. But your array contains the result of the call to `UpdateService.saveData()`. And this function doesn't return anything. So the array contains `undefined` instead of a promise.

`saveData()` must return a promise:

```
saveData: function(answers, answerId) {
    return SaveQuestionAnswerResource.save(...).$promise;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome bro. It worked for me  thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var promises = [];

promises.push(UpdateService.saveData(questionAnswers, $scope.contentStrategy.id));

     $q.all(promises).then(function(result)
        {
        // do what you want here
        });
```

Comment: $q.all() expects an array of promises. Not an array of arrays of undefined.

Comment: That's what the OP is *already* doing, just written in a slightly different way.